# Convert CSV file to shapefile and show data in view

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-3, csv

I'm searching differents methods with QGIS to convert my CSV file to shapefile and show my points in the view. I tested differents methods that I have seen on the forum and It's not really what I want to get. In the CSV, my columns are like this : name, latitude,longitude

```
Espoey,43.248333,0.155
Chelle-Debat,43.303661346435504,0.224329993128777
PIC DU MIDI,42.933,0.15
Pic-du-Midi,42.93639,0.14278
Tarbes - Ossun - Lourdes,43.187,0.005
[MAE] CollŠge Jean Bouzet - PONTACQ,43.1853389,-0.1094389
Arcizans-Avant,42.98333,-0.1
BagnŠres-de-Luchon,42.8,0.6
Luz-Saint-Sauveur,42.87191,-0.00322
Boss•st-Central,42.776111,0.689722
Soumoulou,43.2656,-0.1875
Benasque, Refugio De Estos,42.683333,0.483333
Nay,43.18333,-0.26667
Saramon,43.52318,0.76349
BIELSA REFUGIO DE PI,42.669,0.099
ERISTE REFUGIO ANGEL,42.628,0.46
```

---

@J.Monticolo yes I did this method, the link "QGIS documentation" and I have my points in the view. My last question, all my points are on Africa. But they are normaly on all the world. It's a projection problem... ?

[image]

Comment: Where's the problem ? What do u want ?

Comment: I copy the text in code format

Comment: You can use the QGIS built-in `Delimited text` and specify latitude and longitude fields ([QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#importing-a-delimited-text-file))or take a look or specify CSV data types : https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/

Comment: Can you tell the spatial extent of the created layer? In your example, which column is lat and which is lon?